# How to catch fullscreen event of tinyMCE in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce-4

I have add tinyMCE in may website which is using angular. I'm not able to catch full screen event of tinyMCE. I've checked the topic here and tried many method, but still no success.

-With the code below in editor setting I'm able to catch "change", "redo", "undo" event:

```
setting = {
  selector: 'textarea',
  ...
  setup: function(e) {
    e.on('undo', function () {
      some codes;
    });
  },
};
```

but 'fullscreen' seems not work here, neither the button on the toorbar, nor the one in the menu.

-I also tried to get it by finding the fullscreen class in the DOM:

```
if ( angular.element('.mce-fullscreen').length ) {
    console.log('fullscreen');
  }
```

Anyone have some hints, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try the `FullscreenStateChanged` event? `e.on('FullscreenStateChanged', function() { console.log("toogle"); })`

Comment: Thank you, it works fine with "FullscreenStateChanged" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the `fullscreen` plugin you will see this line:

```
editor.fire('FullscreenStateChanged', {state: fullscreenState});
```

...so when you go to full screen the editor will emit the `FullscreenStateChanged` event.  You can then use that event like this:

```
setup: function (editor) {
   editor.on('FullscreenStateChanged', function () {
       console.log('FullscreenStateChanged event fired.');
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer:), btw, where am I able to check the sorce code, please?

Comment: The TinyMCE download includes all the source code for the product.  Each plugin is in its own folder inside a `plugins` folder within TinyMCE.  Each plugin has a minified and non-minified version so you can always look at the non-minified code to see what event a certain part of the editor is firing.